# How to embed javascript and JSON into Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, json, wordpress

I am trying to get some javascript/JSON to work with Wordpress.

I am trying to get this to work on my Wordpress website. I've registered and enqueued the particles.min.js and it shows up just fine. I don't know how to pull the JSON or load it onto the page. I keep getting errors saying "particlesJS is not defined"

Here's the link I am working with - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

It says:

Load particles.js and configure the particles:

**index.html**

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script src="particles.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
/* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

**particles.json**

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    }
etc...
```

My question is how do I get this to work on a specific Wordpress page? Do I need to enqueue the app.js as well as particles.min.js? I don't know where to put what, and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the sequence of your `app.js` and `particles.min.js` in terms of loading? It maybe because you've defined code for the particles library in `app.js` while `app.js` is enqueued before `particles.min.js`. Make sense?

Comment: I haven't enqueued `app.js` yet. I was wondering if I had to, since it seems to be what is pulling the json from the json file. I've enqueued `particles.min.js` via `functions.php`, and then I would assume just add inline scripts on a particular page in Wordpress... like this `<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script src="particles.js"></script>`, after styling that id in CSS.